# How to create/save cropped images from an image? (will convert images to base64)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]

Let's suppose we have two square data

```
taggedImages: {
  0: {id:0, left:100, top:100, thumbSize:100, type: 'A', seasons: ['All', 'All']},
  1: {id:1, left:200, top:200, thumbSize:100, type: 'B', seasons: ['All', 'All']},
},
```

Can we create/save two new `<Image />` components from `<Image />`?

**Given**

1. left, top, width, height of the each square
2. the width and height of the entire image

**My Approach**

1. Somehow I cache the images to certain paths (file://blahblah, file://blahblah2)
2. Convert them to base64 when it's saved. (I will send multiple images via HTTP)

Any good approach or idea will be highly appreciated

**UPDATE** I'm using React Native

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it sounds like you want to crop two images from an existing Image, right? PHP [imagecrop](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecrop.php) would do the trick.

You could use it like this:

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpg('/path/to/source.jpg');
$img1 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 100, 'y' => 100, 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100]);
if ($img1 !== FALSE) {
    imagejpg($img1, '/path/to/square-1.png');
}
$img2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 200, 'y' => 200, 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100]);
if ($img2 !== FALSE) {
    imagejpg($img2, '/path/to/square-2.png');
}
```

You could do so `foreach` uploaded picture if there's multiple pics.

Comment: I really appreciate your input. Maybe I didn't mention it clearly but I'm using React Native so I can't use PHP imagecrop. :) So your answer may be helpful for others.

Comment: Ah, damn - I overlooked the Tags in your question... Sorry, I'm new to using the mobile app.